# Custom View partially drawn in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I want to use the custom view to draw a square onto the root layout (a RelativeLayout) of my activity. However, when x != 0 or y != 0, the square will only be partially drawn.

When x = 0 and y = 0 (The 3x3 grid is drawn by another custom view)
[image]

When x = 100 and y = 0

[image]

I also set its onTouchListener, and when I clicked the area surrounded by red line, it still fired. But I don't know why the X and Y of the View are not identical with the X and Y of the square shown.

The code to add my view to the layout

```
        PieceView view = new PieceView(this, x, y, widthOfSquare, 0xFF5DADE2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthOfSquare, widthOfSquare);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = (int)x;
        layoutParams.topMargin = (int)y;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        rootLayout.addView(view);
```

My custom view

```
public class PieceView extends View{
    private static final int strokeWidth = 5;
    private Paint paint;
    private RectF rect;

    public PieceView(Context context, float x, float y, float size, int color) {
        super(context);
        init(x, y, size, color);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int desiredWidth = (int)rect.width();
        int desiredHeight = (int)rect.height();

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int width;
        int height;

        //Measure Width
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //Must be this size
            width = widthSize;
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //Can't be bigger than...
            width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
        } else {
            //Be whatever you want
            width = desiredWidth;
        }

        //Measure Height
        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //Must be this size
            height = heightSize;
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //Can't be bigger than...
            height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
        } else {
            //Be whatever you want
            height = desiredHeight;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }

    private void init(float x, float y, float size, int color){
        paint = new Paint();
        rect = new RectF(x, y, x + size, y + size);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm wondering whether I should use

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = (int)x;
layoutParams.topMargin = (int)y;
```

or I should use

```
view.setX(x)
view.setY(y)
```

to specify the position of my square. If the ViewGroup I'm adding it to is a RelativeLayout with `match_parent = true` and it is the root layout of the Activity, is it different between two methods?

I've been stuck for hours and really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is about the coordinates. In onDraw(), the coordinate system of canvas is of the View, not the global one. For example, if View.x = 100, View.y = 0, then the code in onDraw() will draw a rectangle whose top-left corner is (100+100, 0) in the global coordinate system.